# Horizontal/Vertical Scroll

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a container with a card layout(horizontal). Each card is a scrollable component (vertical).

I want to edit the identificaition of each of those two type of scroll, because it actually allow to do Diagonal scroll and I do not want that at all

How do I do that?

I can't find anything in the doc that would allow me to do that.

PS I don't care if I have to work in private classes

Answer (score -1):

Aught to be able to use the [scrollable config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-scrollable).

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'horizontal'
}
```

If you are dealing with a lot of card items see the [defaults config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-defaults) as well, might save you some typing!

If that doesn't work please post some code and I'll try to get you an example.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: The problem is not being unable to change card (horizontal scroll) it is that being a card layout with horizontal scroll and that every card is something that vertically scrolls, make it possible to diag scroll which is not intended and ugly.

I want to replace the way they identify vertical scroll vs horizontal scroll.

Comment: Fawar, not sure I follow the problem but it sounds fun...any chance you could post some code or put together a fiddle? I'd be more than willing to work on this w/you.

Comment: I can't post code, but if you want to try its quite simple to reproduce.

Create a container with a layout set to Card.
In this container add Dataview.List (3x);

Try to scroll Vertical or Horizontal but not both at the same time (Diagonal)

See the problem? Normally a card layout should be activated by swipe, but here it's clear that it is drag event and it is actived simultaneously with the scroll (vertical drag).

So I am trying to seperate those two to achieve the desired result of having a scroll/vertical and a swipe not a drag to switch  card.